# Minimum Advertised Price doesn't work on product page Magento 2.3.1

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I have installed theme SM Shopping from magentech and noticed that MAP price doesnt work on a frontend. I enabled it in configuration, but still nothing. Please advise how I can maybe manually add it to category page and product page

Answer (score 0):

Turned that when we saved configuration to use MAP it didn't save it in database, that's why it didn't work on a frontend.